# jQuery .fn is saying "not a function"

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I call this custom function

```
$.fn.inputBoxHelper = function () {
    var args = arguments[0] || {};
    var matchingElem = $.grep(this, function (e) { return $(e).val() == $(e).attr('title'); });
    $(matchingElem).addClass(args.className);

    this.bind({
        focus: function(){
            if ($(this).val().trim() == $(this).attr('title')) { $(this).val(emptyString).removeClass('gray'); }
        },
        blur: function(){
            if ($(this).val().trim() == emptyString) { $(this).val($(this).attr('title')).addClass('gray'); }
        }
    });
    return this;
}
```

Like this

```
$('input:text').inputBoxHelper({ className: 'gray' });
```

It gives me the error when I call it

```
$("input:text,input:checkbox").inputBoxHelper is not a function
file:///D:/repository/scripts/script_tests/test.js
Line 20
```

Even when I change the function to just

```
$.fn.inputBoxHelper = function () {return this;}
```

it does the same thing.  It seems to run fine and work correctly as all the functionality works on the input boxes but get the error.  Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Are you certain you're not calling the plugin in your code before you've created it?

Comment: You're also relying on $ not being hijacked by another library. When creating plugins, it's safer to use jQuery.fn or (function($) { $.fn.etc })(jQuery); http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

Comment: Patrick: you were so right.  Even though the function above this one worked just fine, this one was for some reason not firing until later.  Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. I'll add my comment as an answer so you can confirm it is resolved.

Comment: thanks @James that solved my problem! :)

Answer (score 17):

Check that you're not loading jQuery into the page twice. Some plugins or plugin libraries like to include jQuery. So it can overwrite your existing jQuery instance and override the `$` and `jQuery` variables with a new – fresh – instance causing existing plugins to be undefined. Plugins are added to the prototype of jQuery when they are defined. So if you destroy the only instance of that object, then the prototype is reset to its original form. And therefore those plugins are no longer part of that prototype.

Also, it may be nothing, [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) is reporting that you're missing a semicolon on the last line of that function definition you posted. It ought to be:

```
$.fn.inputBoxHelper = function () {
  var args = arguments[0] || {};
  var matchingElem = $.grep(this, function (e) { return $(e).val() == $(e).attr('title'); });
  $(matchingElem).addClass(args.className);

  this.bind({
     focus: function(){
          if ($(this).val().trim() == $(this).attr('title')) { $(this).val(emptyString).removeClass('gray'); }
      },
      blur: function(){
          if ($(this).val().trim() == emptyString) { $(this).val($(this).attr('title')).addClass('gray'); }
      }
  });
  return this;
};
```

It's **always** a good idea to run all of your javascript through JSlint. It can help you find stuff that you might spend hours looking for otherwise.

Comment: I had this problem. If you load jquery (have an include to jquery) again after doing $.fn... then your function will disappear

Comment: @adinas: That is because the `jQuery` or `$` variables are being overwritten with a fresh instance of jQuery. The new instance doesn't have the new methods (*plug-ins*) added to it's prototype.

Comment: Fixed the issue for me. Was loading two different versions of jquery!

Answer (score 4):

The plugin needs to be loaded before it can be used.

Comments above confirm that OP was attempting to use the plugin before it was loaded.